# (PHP) End session button

Tags: php, session, counter, kill

I'm trying to create a game, and when you win (or lose) the game you reach an end-screen.

Since the game works with a max amount of attempts (5), the game ends when the counter reaches 5.

So when you reach the win/lose-screen, you get a button prompt which allows the user to start a new game.
Needlessly, the session needs to be killed when pressing that button, so that when it returns to the game page the game is restarted with a fresh counter of 0.

Now my current code of the win-page is as follows.

```
<?php 
session_start();
##error_reporting(0);
##ini_set('display_errors', 0);
?> 

<div align="center">


<h1>Gefeliciteerd!<br /></h1>
<?php echo "Het correcte woord is: ";
echo($_SESSION['testen'])?> 
<br />
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="lingtesttesttest.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Speel nog een keer!">
</FORM>
</div>
```

As seen in the code, when you click the button you're linked back to the game PHP... Now I need the added function of it killing the session after pressing the button.
I've looked on Stackoverflow, and other forums. But the solutions I have found often go to a different ''killpage''. I don't want that, I want to return right back to the game page.

Comment: Why not use jQuery/Ajax? You would not have to re-direct or re-fresh the page and just destroy it.

Comment: You could just set the session variable back to zero...

Comment: Sidenote: `METHOD="LINK"` there is no method LINK. Use GET or POST. This will cause the form to fall back to the default method, GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it way too complicated for myself...

I added this to the bottom of my win/lose screen, and it shows every stat I want to show, and it kills it after it shows everything.

```
<?php 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Funny, I was going to mention that earlier. Plus, did you read my comment about your method LINK? That's invalid.

Comment: I changed it to get now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can work:

```
if(isset($_POST['start_new_game'])){
  session_unset($_SESSION['session_game']);
  // or you can try this also but be sure that there aren't any other $_SESSION variables associated with the user session_destroy();
}
else{
  // do anything you want to do
}
```

And you have set the method of the form to LINK `METHOD = "LINK"`. As there is no such method as "LINK" so it will cause php script to fail. You have to use `POST` or `GET` as @Fred-ii- mentioned.

Comment: This won't work with OP's `METHOD="LINK`. This will cause the form to fall back to the default method, GET.

Comment: Yeah I see it now and also gave the comment to him through my answer. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome Gourab. It was just to make sure if OP planned on using a GET method, since it was not specified in the code/question as to how the form was being for/as. There are no GET/POST variables anywhere in the question. *Cheers*